# Why is "hanging people" such a central theme in the Megillah?

Tags: purim, megillat-esther

(inspired by [this tweet](https://twitter.com/RavJesseHorn/status/1104440985864540160))

There's so much hanging being spoken about in Megillas Esther.
Any idea as to why this is such a common theme in the Megillah?

[2:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.2.23?lang=bi&with=Malbim&lang2=en)

> "**וַיִּתָּל֥וּ** שְׁנֵיהֶ֖ם עַל־עֵ֑ץ"

[5:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.5.14?lang=bi&with=Megillah&lang2=en)

> " יַֽעֲשׂוּ־עֵץ֮ גָּבֹ֣הַּ חֲמִשִּׁ֣ים אַמָּה֒ וּבַבֹּ֣קֶר ׀ אֱמֹ֣ר לַמֶּ֗לֶךְ **וְיִתְל֤וּ** אֶֽת־מָרְדֳּכַי֙ עָלָ֔יו"

[6:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.6.4?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en)

> " וְהָמָ֣ן בָּ֗א לַחֲצַ֤ר בֵּית־הַמֶּ֙לֶךְ֙ הַחִ֣יצוֹנָ֔ה לֵאמֹ֣ר לַמֶּ֔לֶךְ **לִתְלוֹת֙** אֶֽת־מָרְדֳּכַ֔י"

[7:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.7.10?lang=bi&with=Megillah&lang2=he)

> "**וַיִּתְלוּ֙** אֶת־הָמָ֔ן עַל־הָעֵ֖ץ"

[8:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.8.7?lang=bi&with=Megillah&lang2=en)

> " וְאֹתוֹ֙ **תָּל֣וּ** עַל־הָעֵ֔ץ"

[9:13-14](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.9.13-14?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en)

> " וְאֵ֛ת עֲשֶׂ֥רֶת בְּנֵֽי־הָמָ֖ן **תָּלֽוּ** ... וְאֵ֛ת עֲשֶׂ֥רֶת בְּנֵֽי־הָמָ֖ן יִתְל֥וּ עַל־הָעֵֽץ"

[9:25](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.9.25?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en)

> "**וְתָל֥וּ** אֹת֛וֹ וְאֶת־בָּנָ֖יו עַל־הָעֵֽץ"

Comment: I disagree with the premise of the Tweet. Nothing says they were *killed* by hanging. Perhaps their corpses were hung, which is something even the Sanhedrin would do (Devarim 21:22, using the same wording: ותלית אתו על עץ).

Comment: Hanging was the preferred Persian method of execution.

Comment: @Yishai interesting- source?

Comment: @DonielF nowhere in the megillah does it state any prior form of death and THEN hanging- Sanhedrin's hanging would be after the capital punishment we know of was administered (ie the method of *misah* had already been established in the Torah)

Comment: @alicht Technically, nowhere in the Megillah does it say that anybody died in the first place.

Comment: @DonielF it's a logical assumption- unless you want to argue these people were just hung for fun and then let down (still alive) and went along their merry way?

Comment: @alicht No, what I'm arguing is that the same way the Sanhedrin would hang their victims to publicize their deaths as a warning against following in their footsteps, so, too, did the Medes do.

Comment: @DonielF it's an interesting idea- more of a *chiddush* then what all of us assume/ learned as *kinder*. Any sources which support this idea?

Comment: @alicht If I had sources to support this idea I'd post it as an answer. :)

Comment: Re @DonielF's comments: it's clear that the sons of Haman were hung after being killed: see 9:6–14

Comment: @DonielF: although the tweet does, this question doesn't claim anyone was killed by hanging

Comment: @alicht, http://www.capitalpunishmentuk.org/hanging2.html Hanging originated as a method of execution in Persia (now Iran) about 2500 years ago for male criminals only, (women were strangled at the stake for the sake of decency!)

Comment: @Yishai https://www.ligonier.org/blog/was-haman-hanged-or-impaled/ (Which perhaps suggests that the 10 sons of Haman were formed into a kebab... New Purim custom?